# Get the average value with mongoose query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm getting a list of 'spot' with mongoose filtered by location and other stuff, with the code below which works fine.
But I want the value of 'rate' to be a $avg (average) of all reviews and not the list of the reviews. It's an aggregation of another collection.

this is what I get:

```
{
"_id":"5f0ade7d1f84460434524d3d",
"name":"Fly",
...
"rate":[
    {"_id":"5f0bfca64ca1cc02ffe48faf","spot_id":"5f0ade7d1f84460434524d3d","rate":3}, 
    {"_id":"5f0bfdb44ca1cc02ffe48fb0","spot_id":"5f0ade7d1f84460434524d3d","rate":2}, 
    {"_id":"5f0bfdb44ca1cc02ffe48fb1","spot_id":"5f0ade7d1f84460434524d3d","rate":1}
  ]
},
```

but I would like this kind of result:

```
{
   "_id":"5f0ade7d1f84460434524d3d",
   "name":"Fly",
   ...
   "rate": 2
},
```

I tried many different things, and I guess I need to use $group but can't figure out how to get the right output.

the reviews schema:

```
const reviewsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
    spot_id: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
    rate: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
})
```

the spot Schema

```
const spotsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: ObjectId,
        required: true,
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },
    ...
})
```

The code:

```
Spots.aggregate
  ([
    {
      $geoNear: {
          near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude) ] },
          distanceField: "location",
          maxDistance: parseInt(distance) * 1000,
          query: {
            $and: [
              { $or : filter },
              { $or : closed },
              { published: true }
            ]
          }
      }
    },
    { $match: {} },
    {
      $lookup:{
        from: 'reviews',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'spot_id',
        as: 'rate'
      }
    },
  ])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close, you just have to actually calculate the `avg` value which can be done using [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [$avg](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/) like so:

```
{
    $addFields: {
      rate: {
        $avg: {
          $map: {
            input: "$rate",
            as: "datum",
            in: "$$datum.rate"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/qesSuwS1_lz)